# Can we get rid of "& Photographic Editing" or change it to something else?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, site-attributes

It seems like once a week we get someone in here asking about "How can I do this non-photo-related thing with Photoshop?" It appears to come from the name of the site, "Photography *and Photographic Editing*".

To avoid confusion, should we rename the site? I'd suggest "Photography and Post-Processing," but perhaps there's a better term.

Comment: "Photography" is simple and inclusive. It does not need to be qualified.

Comment: Rather than add a 'me too' answer, I guess I'll add a 'me too' comment. :-P Yes, let's ditch the 'Photographic Editing' from the title.

Comment: I "ditto" Labnut and Jay. ;)

Comment: Me four! I agree 100% with labnut on that, "Photography" is sufficient.

Comment: It seems like there's a pretty broad consensus for renaming the site to simply "Photography". When can this happen?

Comment: Ditto @Reid. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7486 as an example of confusion. Let's make this happen!

Comment: @Evan New header logo text is up on live now.

Comment: w00t, thanks Jin! looks great :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We certainly can get rid of it. So the site title will simply be "Photography?" How does the community feel about this?

Comment: Looks like we feel good about it.

Comment: +1; let's get rid of it.

Comment: Throw in my vote behind the suggestion!

Answer (score 10):

Answer: Yes. We can get rid of "and photographic editing".

Removing it entirely is my preference. We can explain in the FAQ that post-processing (digitally or analog!) and printing are covered.

Answer (score 9):

I vote **"yes"**, remove the reference to "Photographic Editing".

This Q&A forum already has what I feel is a *disproportionate* bent towards the physical "tools and gear" and less so for the *technical/artistic* side of photography (i.e. composition, lighting, exposure, etc).

I would have no objection to calling this site simply **"Photography"** to add a bit of weight to that focus.

Besides, gear selection and post processing are already an entrenched part of the photographic process, hence an *implicit* part of this site. Perhaps getting rid of the "… Photographic Editing" nomenclature would dissuade anyone who might conflate photography-based "post-processing" with other types of image manipulation and graphic artistry.

Answer (score 3):

I agree, just call it photography (editing & PP is an inherent part of photography)

[I would have just upvoted one of the other answers but I aint got the rep]

Comment: welcome to photo.SE! You seem new here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm fine with a name change, but there needs to be at *least* one "no" answer so that people can vote that way. :-P

FWIW, I don't see much of a problem with the name as-is. *Photographic* editing implies *photo*-related Photoshop ( *Photo* shop?) questions. Changing the name might not dissuade those people from posting anyway. (But we can certainly find out.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm OK with a name change but I don't think we should remove the photographic editing if we still want to accept questions about it.

There is a difference photography and photographic editing but it's a blurry line for many people. If this were only 'Photography' then some questions would be subjectively off-topic. We should avoid that.

You can call it post-processing, image butchering (just kidding) or something else. I think the idea is simply to avoid questions that are purely graphic operations.

The other option is to create a separate site and make this one 'Photography' and the other 'Image Editing' or 'Image Manipulation'. That would be a nice slit actually.